# WSO2IS 4.6.0 can't process the SAML LogoutRequest

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

The WSO2 Identity Server 4.6.0 can't process the following SAML (SLO) logout request:

```
<saml2p:LogoutRequest Destination="https://idp:9443/samlsso"
ID="_f2a42cceb9e680b8d91fafd44d05391d27afa997"
IssueInstant="2014-03-26T18:18:10.842Z"
Version="2.0"
xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
>
<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">sp</saml2:Issuer>
<saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
>REALM/email@example.com</saml2:NameID>
</saml2p:LogoutRequest>
```

It gives:

```
[2014-03-26 19:18:11,009] ERROR -  Error Processing the Logout Request {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor}
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
        at java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:3212)
        at org.opensaml.xml.util.LazyList.get(LazyList.java:89)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
        at java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:3212)
        at org.opensaml.xml.util.LazyList.get(LazyList.java:89)
        at org.opensaml.xml.util.XMLObjectChildrenList.get(XMLObjectChildrenList.java:96)
        at org.opensaml.xml.util.XMLObjectChildrenList.get(XMLObjectChildrenList.java:32)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor.process(LogoutRequestProcessor.java:114)
        ... 38 more
```

Any idea why, and how to remediate?

UPDATE:

I believe it is related to the element of SessionIndex, but according to the http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf SAML documentation it is optional in LogoutRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the above error message, but maybe you are on the right track.

In the document you posted also says the sp MUST include a SessionIndex (it says "at least one") , see line 1302

After all if you do not include a session index, how should the idp know what session to terminate and which other session participants should be informed about the logout?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SessionIndex is a must.

SessionIndex  - This is the session identifier that is used to identify the user session with both IDP and SP for given user.

Pleae refer [How SAML2 Single Logout Works](http://soasecurity.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/) for more details.